# How to turn off keyboard backlight of and Alienware M14X laptop

Tags: backlight, alienware

OK, I have an Alienware M14X and the keyboard backlight is always on and I can't turn it off... Google didn't  me much. I want to turn it off because it's disturbing sometimes

I uninstalled Windows OS from my laptop so I can't really disable it from there

Answer (score 1):

Change the color to black and it will be off.

Comment: This appears to be accurate: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w81_4riV2Q Your answer would be much improved if you would explain how to accomplish this without Windows.

Comment: Could be, but how from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

For GNU-Linux systems you can use [alienware-kbl](http://rsm.imap.cc/software/gnu-linux/software/alienware-kbl). With that program you can control the lights of alienware computers.